# How to get the acolumns type from fnSettings() in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have to set the values to the aocolumns from history so i have to know the type of the filter.I find how to do for input.Now I got blocked because of select.Thank in advance
my code:

```
$.each(oTable.fnSettings().aoPreSearchCols,function(filterIndex,filterValue){
     //console.log(theadRow.find("th:nth-child(8):selected").val(filterValue.sSearch).removeClass("search_init"));
     (filterValue.sSearch)?theadRow.find('th:nth-child('+(filterIndex+1)+') input').val(filterValue.sSearch).removeClass("search_init"):''; });
```

Comment: any one can help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work (untested):

```
$.each(oTable.fnSettings().aoPreSearchCols, function(filterIndex, filterValue){
   if(filterValue.sSearch != ""){
      $('th', theadRow).eq(filterIndex + 1).find('input, select')
         .val(filterValue.sSearch)
         .removeClass("search_init");
   }
});
```